# Rails Master Key in Gitlab.com CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab, gitlab-ci, secret-key

I am trying to set up `gitlab.com` continuous integration(CI) for one of my private projects. But `rails db:migrate` is failing with the following error:

> ActiveSupport::EncryptedFile::MissingKeyError: Missing encryption key to decrypt file with. Ask your team for your master key and write it to /builds/shubh-muhurat/Backend/config/master.key or put it in the ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY']

The `master key` should not be there in the repository, but if I set `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` using `.gitlab-ci.yml` I have to commit the master key to the repository.

So is there a better way of putting the master key.

PS: I am using `gitlab.com` CI.

**Version**:
Rails 5.2.0.beta2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this by adding the master key to the projects secret variables and then injecting it during the before_script phase:

`- echo "$MASTER_KEY" > config/master.key`

Comment: Be careful, Gitlab CI variables masking is not secure, it's a "best-effort" feature to prevent revealing accidentally a value, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#mask-a-cicd-variable.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit of research for finding the easiest way of declaring the variables, I came across the `Variables` section in GitLab. The `Variables` section is located under the repository CI/CD setting. There is also an option of making your variables protected.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and solved it using a workaround by injecting a temporary dummy master.key and credentials.yml.enc while building the image. This allows my CI to use the dummy master.key without revealing the real key.

**Workaround in Dockerfile**

```
# Precompile assets
# We use dummy master.key and credentials.yml.enc to workaround the fact that
# assets:precompile needs them but we don't want the real master.key to be built
# into the container. We will inject RAILS_MASTER_KEY env var when starting the
# container.

RUN if [[ "$RAILS_ENV" == "production" ]]; then \
      mv config/credentials.yml.enc config/credentials.yml.enc.backup; \
      mv config/credentials.yml.enc.sample config/credentials.yml.enc; \
      mv config/master.key.sample config/master.key; \
      bundle exec rails assets:precompile; \
      mv config/credentials.yml.enc.backup config/credentials.yml.enc; \
      rm config/master.key; \
    fi
```